# FBPlacePickerViewController return nothing when used in Swift

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift, ios8, facebook-ios-sdk

I try to use Facebook's PlacePicker in Swift, but it return nothing despite I have checked the session and tried to debug in -dataDidChange method for proper request.

I'm afraid the code is too long then I put it in my gist, thank you in advance.

https://gist.github.com/macbaszii/de6daf32f06b33406174